Artificial Intelligence in PCB component definitions?
Has anyone tried using one of the popular AIs eg GPT, to create component footprints and symbols from data sheets for various PCB design packages?
Is it possible?
I want something that can do the hard work of creating package definitions for semi-obsolete PCB design tools such as Proteus

Looks like you're going to be the first to try. Watch out for hallucinations, which are not as absent as we would like in human generated content.

There are tools that can extract this information from supplier documentation. I know of at least one person doing so to create Altium (yuk) footprints and symbols.

Why would you use AI that can't do it, instead of a script that can generate you parametrized footprints based on standards? Also the next problem is, you would need to know which PCB manufaturing and soldering process the manufacturer uses, to tune the parameters accordingly to compensate for effects that distort the fooprint during PCB manufacture and to make it solder well, or to even to generate a proper stencil for the properties of the used solder paste.

At least one of the large CAD software companies have some beta version of an integrated tool that is supposed to help with reading data sheets and finding specs. Haven't tried it, and it definitely can't do full footprints on its own.

Yes; because this is not at all what these popular networks have been trained for, the results are unusable. Try typing: "make a technical drawing with dimensions of a QFN-32 package footprint" into one and see whether you'd trust the footprint. Pasting two Deliberate model-generated images below:


The AlbedoXL model seems to have learned from MC Escher:

Doesn't mean generative neural networks couldn't be used to generate package drawings or footprints from text, but currently, microsoft copilot refuses to generate source code for kicad footprints.

ah, image creation is taking some time today, will add later.

I was looking forward to seeing that image.

For what it's worth, I asked ChatGPT to "Please make a technical drawing with the dimensions of a QFN-32 package footprint." The resulting image is so inaccurate that it can't even be meaningfully criticized.

@TannerSwett, but at least it's cool looking.  I like how it's put some details outside the actual page area.  Many of my colleagues seem to do that, I can only assume so since I have to ask them for so many details that are never present on the designs.

@TannerSwett Wow, I love that picture, and I'm not even sarcastic!

I've seen some GPT website to generate a chip PCB footprint description/source file, for some EDA, maybe KiCad. It did look like a footprint for the package, unfortunately the copper pads were too large and touched each other. The only other problem was that the pads were offset from the chip outline. Perhaps the problem is to generate the CAD drawing image for it, instead of asking to generate the text file that describes the footprint - I mean, it can generate simple programs in various other languages too.

@Justme you're right, the fact that it can generate reasonably accurate code given instructions is why I'm hopeful the same mechanism could be trained to fulfill such purposes. But that would take a considerable training corpus, and manual verification for the beginning.
